# How to save a struct to realm in swift?

Tags: swift, realm

It is easy to use Realm with classes by inheriting from `Object`. But how would I save a `struct` containing several fields to realm in Swift? E.g.

```
struct DataModel {
    var id = 0
    var test = "test"
}
```

I know the documentation is clear about supported types. But maybe there is nice workaround or - even better - someone from realm could write about future plans about structs.

Comment: Did you consider using a protocol-oriented database library like GRDB.swift? Since it is protocol-oriented, you get fetching and persistence methods for your custom structs and class hierarchies. You don't have to inherit from a base class.

Comment: I was just reading this and just wondering... "why?" Especially with the latest Realm. Aside from the short-term pain of upgrading your structs to classes, is there a really good reason to avoid using classes? My own rule of thumb is that it's a complexity thing. As my structs get more complex, the eventually become classes... and I [think?] I have a problem with that here...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I' suggest you to use protocols, to achive what you want.

**1) Create your Struct**

```
struct Character {
    public let identifier: Int
    public let name: String
    public let realName: String
}
```

**2) Create your Realm Object**

```
final class CharacterObject: Object {
    dynamic var identifier = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var realName = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
```

**3) Use protocols to transform our struct to Realm Object**

```
public protocol Persistable {
    associatedtype ManagedObject: RealmSwift.Object
    init(managedObject: ManagedObject)
    func managedObject() -> ManagedObject
}
```

**4) Make your struct persistable**

```
extension Character: Persistable {
    public init(managedObject: CharacterObject) {
        identifier = managedObject.identifier
        name = managedObject.name
        realName = managedObject.realName
    }
    public func managedObject() -> CharacterObject {
        let character = CharacterObject()
        character.identifier = identifier
        character.name = name
        character.realName = realName
        return character
    }
}
```

With these tools in place, we are ready to implement the insertion methods of our persistence layer.

**5) Exemple to write datas**

```
public final class WriteTransaction {
    private let realm: Realm
    internal init(realm: Realm) {
        self.realm = realm
    }
    public func add<T: Persistable>(_ value: T, update: Bool) {
        realm.add(value.managedObject(), update: update)
    }
}

// Implement the Container
public final class Container { 
    private let realm: Realm
    public convenience init() throws {
        try self.init(realm: Realm())
    }
    internal init(realm: Realm) {
        self.realm = realm
    }
    public func write(_ block: (WriteTransaction) throws -> Void) 
    throws {
        let transaction = WriteTransaction(realm: realm)
        try realm.write {
            try block(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

**5) Use the magic!**

```
let character = Character(
    identifier: 1000,
    name: "Spiderman",
    realName: "Peter Parker"
)
let container = try! Container()
try! container.write { transaction in
    transaction.add(character)
}
```

Amazing source : [Using Realm with Value Types](https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/using-realm-with-value-types-b69947741e8b#.cnmq2c7ci) & [My Article](https://medium.com/@ludovicjamet/how-to-use-struct-with-realm-615fcbc8f0ee)

Comment: Some update from the article that you shared:

 transaction.add(character, update: true)

Answer (score 16):

To save a `struct` in Realm, means copying the data into a Realm `Object`. The reason why Realm `Objects` are classes and not `structs` is because they are not inert values, but auto-updating objects that represent the persisted data in Realm. This has practical benefits, such as the fact that a Realm `Object`'s data is lazy loaded.

You can take advantage of Realm's approach by responding to the change notifications from a Realm instance. For example if your `UITableView` data source is based off an array property on a Realm `Object`, as long as you have an instance of that object, you are guaranteed that after the notification it represents the correct values. Used properly this can simplify your code versus having multiple copies of values as structs.

Answer (score 15):

### Swift 4 shortest answer

Save structs as Data in Realm

```
struct MyStruct : Codable { // Variables here }

class MyRealObject : Object {

    @objc private dynamic var structData:Data? = nil

    var myStruct : MyStruct? {
        get {
            if let data = structData {
                return try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: data)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            structData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

### Use the magic

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
      let myReal = MyRealObject()
      myReal.myStruct = MyStruct(....)
      realm.add(myReal)
}
```

Comment: perfect ! Thank you - (small mistake still in your code: `carrierData` seems to be `structData` - isn't it ?)

Comment: And maybe it is good to add     `override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["myStruct"]
    }` .... - just to make it clear the myStruct-property is ignored by Realm...

Comment: Doesn't this simply store a JSON blob into the DB?  Which inhibits the efficiency of utilizing predicates to search and filter on that data.

Comment: what about linked objects?

Answer (score 5):

You can do what suggests Ludovic, or you can automate that process and get rid of that boilerplate code for each of your structs by using [Unrealm](https://github.com/arturdev/Unrealm).

[image]

Comment: That looks really cool, thinking about using Realm and didn't want to change all my structs to classes.  Nice work.

Comment: Many congratulations on a very nice library. I am very tempted to give it a try as it alleviates the need for maintaining two clone models - one struct and one corresponding Object class. However, will realm notifications work on the Swift native types?