# How to design database model in Swift if using Protocol and Struct only?

Tags: swift, database, core-data, struct, realm

Since Swift Protocol Oriented Programming, struct, value typed and functional programming are improving in Swift. But how about the databases. I have used 2 database: Cora Data and Realm. Both required a class to be inherited from Object (Realm) or ManagedObject(Core Data)

My question is: What is the database model to use If I want to design my application model with struct only?

Thanks

Comment: It is not exactly same, my question is not required using realm.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked in a similar question before: [How to save a struct to realm in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060391/how-to-save-a-struct-to-realm-in-swift)

Suffice it to say, Realm's implementation details (and Core Data as well) rely on the Objective-C runtime, so their models cannot be structs.