# Can't save nested struct to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to save struct data to Realm. I could save not nested struct. But I cant save nested one. I get compile error: **Struct 'self.foodList' must be completely initialized before a member is stored to**

I tried everything I know but no success. Help me to solve the problem )

Struct:

```
struct MenuListDisplayItems {
    
    let menuID: String
    let foodList: FoodList
    // let foodList = List<RealmFoodList>()
}

struct FoodList {
    
    var foodID: String
    var foodName: String
}
```

Realm Object:

```
final class RealmMenuList: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var menuID = ""
    let foodList = RealmFoodList()
}

final class RealmFoodList: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var foodID = ""
    @objc dynamic var foodName = ""
}

extension MenuListDisplayItems: Persistable {
    
    init(managedObject: RealmMenuList) {
        
        menuID = managedObject.menuID
        foodList.foodID = managedObject.foodList.foodID
        foodList.foodName = managedObject.foodList.foodName
    }
    
    func managedObject() -> RealmMenuList {
        
        let subMenuList = RealmMenuList()
        subMenuList.menuID = menuID
        subMenuList.foodList.foodID = foodList.foodID
        subMenuList.foodList.foodName = foodList.foodName
        return subMenuList
    }
}
```

Protocol:

```
protocol Persistable {
    
    associatedtype ManagedObject: RealmSwift.Object
    init(managedObject: ManagedObject)
    func managedObject() -> ManagedObject
}
```

Comment: As shown in the duplicate target, you must declare one-to-one relationships as `Optional` and mark them as `@objc dynamic`. Realm relies on the Obj-C runtime, so any property that you want to persist in Realm __MUST__ be marked `@objc dynamic`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor  Sorry, don't understand how to. :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You're using the older `@objc` format -while that's ok, you should really consider moving the more current syntax; see [Property Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/supported-property-types/) and [objects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/fundamentals/object-models-and-schemas/). The protocol also seems redudant - assign `Object` to your persistable objects. Can you clarify what you're doing and what the issue is (once you've reviewed the documentation)

Comment: @Jay I want to save MenuListDisplayItems struct to Realm. I can save if struct is not nested.
This implementation I took here [Ludovic's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060391/how-to-save-a-struct-to-realm-in-swift)

Comment: That answer is from 5 years ago and a LOT has changed - you really don't need to do all of that - it's way over complicated at this point. First decide if `MenuListDisplayItems` is going to be embedded or managed. If managed, then make it a `class MenuListDisplayItems: Object {` and get rid of the protocols and all the extraneous code. Then do the same thing with `FoodList`. You are good to go after that. I would suggest, as mentioned above, use the newer @Persisted vars and List syntax for `class RealmMenuList` etc. Way simpler and much easier to maintain.